How to open specific a profile chrome without ChromeDriver crashed with RobotFramework and Selenium
I have a site with captcha, I have already opened a chrome profile and logged in to that site. When I launched the test file, Chromedriver opened up the specific profile I selected but then everything stopped and threw an error.
and here, this is my code RobotFramework and Selenium:

My Chrome version: 124.0.6367.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)
so, How to open a specific chrome profile while still maintaining the session with the previously opened profile on the laptop? because, I cannot ask the developer to give me a site without a captcha, so I am forced to open a Chrome profile first and log in manually, then use auto to reopen that profile by specifying the path. but the result is that the session crashes

I am not sure that using backslashes is the root of your problem, but anyway, it could cause issues. I would suggest to escape backslashes:  --user-data-dir\=C:\users\...  should be --user-data-dir\=C:\\users\\....   Or replace to slashes, they work for Windows-based Selenium also:  --user-data-dir\=C:/users/...

@SamMaksymyshyn thank u friend, i thought about that too, but thanks God that still open browser. I will edit it soon.
I really don't understand why when I open the browser and open the correct profile I specified, the session is disconnected in the next step
